# Что означает "каждого первого" в этом контексте?

Tags: значения

Описание [ролика](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsXBtSlUfy8&list=UUq7JZ8ATgQWeu6sDM1czjhg):

> Безнаказанно быть козлом - мечта **каждого первого**! Об игре, позволяющей воплотить эту мечту в жизнь, пусть и виртуально, сейчас и пойдет речь.

Comment: I suppose it is a word by word translation of "everyone". It's quite weird to see "каждого первого" in Russian.

Comment: @DmitryBelyaev Нет, это намеренная игра слов. Как "две большие разницы" вместо "большая разница".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это эквивалентно просто `каждого`.
Дело в том, что эта фраза образована из фраз `каждого второго`, `каждого третьего` и т.д. по аналогии. Она является не совсем правильной, имеет юмористический окрас, но остается вполне понятной.

Comment: "Каждого второго" как например в этом предложении: "Гастрит - болезнь каждого второго человека.", не так ли?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @user4384, да, именно.

Answer (score 2):

Это эмфатический прием, "каждый первый" эквивалентно "все без исключения", "абсолютно каждый". Усиление по сравнению с "каждый" достигается за счет

1. сильного обмана ожиданий: мы ожидаем "мечта каждого второго (третьего, пятого, десятого)";
2. повторения: "каждый" -> "каждый первый" ("точно-преточно");
3. недопущения исключений: один (каждый) из одного (первый), при возможности исключений мы бы сказали "мечта 99 из 100".

Answer (score 1):

This expression has an ironic meaning here and it also puts an emphasis on the expression "**each** person, **absolutely** everybody". This expression can only be used in this context because it doesn't really make sense.

The actual expression is "каждый второй", "каждый третий", "каждый четвёртый", etc. which means "one of two people", "one of three people", "one of four people", etc.

Comment: I do not think it means "absolutely everybody". I think it is less strong than simply "каждого". For me "каждого первого" means "10 of 10 on average, rounded" or "more than 9 of 10". That is it allows some exceptions, but not as much as could affect the statistics (as opposed of simply "каждого" which does not allow exceptions).

Comment: Well, it is something personal, I suppose. Being ironic, this expression also sounds emphatic to me.